# Outlook AddIn for filtering recipients

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I want to build an Outlook AddIn in C# that has a button in the calendar ribbon that the user clicks to create a new meeting with one of their employees.  We want the user (the manager) to be able to select the employee from a filtered list of only their own employees and not have to search through the entire directory.  <del>What is the best way to do this?</del>

*addendum:*
I did some searching and I came across a potential method for the filter.

I know that the "SelectNamesDialog" function will get me an Address Book dialog box:

```
Outlook.SelectNamesDialog snd = Application.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog();
```

I want to combine that with a piece of code I found.  I modified it to return the names of all the manager's direct reports (the employees under the manager).

I think I'm on the right track, but I'm uncertain of what to do next.  How do I now allow the user to select one of these names through the GetSelectNamesDialog?  It is OK if your answer is in psuedocode.

```
// source: "How to: Get Information About Direct Reports of the Current User's Manager" 
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184617.aspx
        private List<string> GetManagerDirectReports()
        {
            List<string> AddressNames = new List<string>();

            Outlook.AddressEntry currentUser = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry;
            if (currentUser.Type == "EX")
            {
                Outlook.ExchangeUser manager = currentUser.GetExchangeUser().GetExchangeUserManager();
                if (manager != null)
                {
                    Outlook.AddressEntries addrEntries = manager.GetDirectReports();
                    if (addrEntries != null)
                    {
                        foreach (Outlook.AddressEntry addrEntry in addrEntries)
                        {
                            //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(addrEntry.Name);
                            AddressNames.Add(addrEntry.Name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return AddressNames;
        }
```

Comment: The best way is Google. This is not a "how to" site. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Good luck.

Comment: Of course I already tried Google, which led me here.. I read the Help pages. I searched for previous questions. My question meets the "on-topic" standards (it is "a specific programming problem" and "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"). I found many other questions that start with "How to" or "How do I" and they are not all code error messages. My question was a constructive question that will 'inspire answers that explain “why” and “how.”'

Comment: You need to show at least some work. This is the kind of site you come to when you are already working on something and hit a wall.

Comment: I have been working on this for several hours and hit a wall.  I have most of the program written.  I am not asking generically "Hey, how do I do programming?"  The question is specifically about filtering the recipients list.  But if you insist upon showing work, I will add a few lines of code into the question, ask what is wrong with it, and hopefully someone will suggest a better way and I'll get the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: That's the way to go. Post some code and you will see the answers flow.

Comment: I think in the process of gathering some code to formulate the question I got myself on track to solve this.  My original searches came up empty because there were no "address book filters" to speak of, but I got more specific and searched for something like "get direct reports" and I found that handy bit of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now seem to be able to post an answer to my own question.

I added a dropdown in the Form Region and added this code to populate the dropdown with names of the manager's direct reports:

```
// Get Outlook list of employees who report to manager, using Exchange data.
List<string> mgrAddressNames = GetManagerDirectReports();

if (mgrAddressNames.Count >= 1)
{
   try
   {
    // System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource bindingSource1;
    // Create a Binding Source to the ComboBox to make values in ComboBox match the results of the list of direct reports.
    System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource bindingSource1 = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource();
    bindingSource1.DataSource = mgrAddressNames;
    EmployeeInvited.DisplayMember = "Value";
    EmployeeInvited.ValueMember = "Key";
    EmployeeInvited.DataSource = bindingSource1.DataSource;

    bindingSource1.Dispose();

(etc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Address book won't let you restrict the list to a subset of some users, so you'd need to come up with you own window that prompts the user for the selection from a pre-filtered list.

Comment: Thanks.  I see that now.  I'm on track of doing just that.

Comment: I was previously not able to answer my own post, but now I can. I added the answer I developed.